# Scrapy follows link but does not return data, possible timing issue?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have tried several settings such as delaying the download time, the console does not seem to have an error, and the selectors return the correct data from Scrapy Shell

The site uses a different prefix on the domain, could this be the cause? slist.amiami.jp
I tried several variations of domains and URLs but all result in the same response of no data returned

Any Idea why it is not collecting any data for the -o CSV file? Thank you if you have any advise

The expected output is to return the JAN code and category text from the product page

```
2021-05-13 23:59:35 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-05-13 23:59:35 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6026
2021-05-13 23:59:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.jp/top/search/list?s_keywords=4967834601246> (referer: None)
2021-05-13 23:59:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.example.jp/top/detail/detail?gcode=TOY-SCL-05454> (referer: https://example.jp/top/search/list?s_keywords=4967834601246)
2021-05-13 23:59:50 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.jp/top/search/list?s_keywords=4543736302216> (referer: None)
2021-05-14 00:00:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://example.jp/top/search/list?s_keywords=44536318620013> (referer: None)
2021-05-14 00:00:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-05-14 00:00:04 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1115,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 29.128242,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
```

```
import scrapy


class exampledataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    allowed_domains = ['example.jp']
    start_urls = ['https://example.jp/top/search/list?s_keywords=4967834601246',
                  'https://example.jp/top/search/list?s_keywords=4543736302216',
                  'https://example.jp/top/search/list?s_keywords=44536318620013',

                  ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('div.product_box a::attr(href)'):
            yield response.follow(link.get(), callback=self.item)


    def item(self, response):
        products = response.css('div.maincontents')
        for product in products:
            yield {
                'JAN': product.css('dd.jancode::text').getall(),
                'title': product.css('div.pankuzu a::text').getall()
            }
```

Comment: Don't put "Solved" in the subject. That is not how Stack Overflow works. Instead mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I know thank you but you are not able to select your own answer and mark it as accepted for 48 hours and the title change is a quick way to notify users the topic has been resolved. I have amended the title now 48 hours has passed and am able to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the `products = response.css('div.maincontents')` selector was incorrect and I had to do 2 separate parent child requests for the data

It also turns out you can simply just YEILD the elements in a list

'''

def output(self, response):

```
    yield {
        'firstitem': response.css('example td:nth-of-type(2)::text').getall(),
        'seconditem': response.css('example td:nth-of-type(2)::text').getall(),
        'thrditem': response.css('example td:nth-of-type(2)::text').getall()
    }
```

'''